# How to ignore error report for Honeybadger in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how to ignore my custom error for Honeybadger in rails app? I just need to raise that error, but don't report it to HB.

I have got my custom error class looks like this:
`class RetrySidekiqJobError < StandardError end`

My current Honeybadger configuration in honeybadger.rb:

```
Honeybadger.configure do |config|
 config.development_environments = %w[development test review]
 config.exceptions.ignore("RetrySidekiqJobError") end
```

But it still reports to HB. Thanks :)

Comment: https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/ruby/getting-started/ignoring-errors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honeybadger's `exceptions.ignore` configuration is already set to a list of exceptions which are [ignored per default](https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/ruby/getting-started/ignoring-errors/#ignore-by-class) and when you want to add more exceptions to that list then you have to [append your exception](https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/ruby/gem-reference/configuration/#configuration-via-ruby-programmatic-) to that list.

The following should work for you:

```
Honeybadger.configure do |config|
  config.development_environments = %w[development test review]
  config.exceptions.ignore += [RetrySidekiqJobError]
end
```